# CSS LESS creating spacing variations

Tags: css, less, less-mixins

I was wondering how to achieve the following CSS with LESS:

```
.spacingTop {
    margin-top: 8px;
}

.spacingRight {
    margin-right: 8px;
}

.spacingBottom {
    margin-bottom: 8px;
}

.spacingLeft {
    margin-left: 8px;
}
```

Should I do something with Iterations?

Comment: Using loops with selector and property name interpolation. I am sure you can find many existing samples in the Less tag :) (Note that the case change of the sides may require JS evaluation)

Comment: There's a big difference between *should* and *can*

Comment: I'd say it solely depends on why you actually need this. For these one-liners I'd leave the CSS as it is (maybe only moved `8px` to variable). Any loop, even in its [most syntactic-sugar form](https://gist.github.com/seven-phases-max/413b039433539d333f81), would look like an overkill for  a list never exceeding 4 items.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you actually want to do? 
Becouse **LESS CSS** was created to organizate your code. This classes are totally diffrent.
I suggest you to use **mixins**. For this i will use this following as example :

```
.margins( @top , @right , @bottom , @left)
{
    margin-top: @top;
    margin-left: @right;
    margin-bottom: @bottom;
    margin-left: @left;
}
```

... and use it later as following

```
.spacingTop
{
    .margins( 15px );
}
```

Hope it helps! :)